# jqueryui button not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I just created a theme using the jquery ui theme roller. I just downloaded it then opened up the index.html that it comes with to display all the content. Everything displays except for the buttons and radio buttons. This is the only part I really care about. Which is kind of funny that this is the only part that doesn't work. I tested it in IE, Chrome, and Firefox and none of them display the buttons. Am I missing something?

Comment: hard to tell without any information at all. best would be if you'd just share the whole zip or link to a test page.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. They do not actually include the code for the button but for everything else.